# How to rename a printer in C++ on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, printing

In WinSpool.h I can enumerate all the printers using the EnumPrinters function, but I cannot find out how to rename an existing printer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`SetPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to rename a printer.

You would set the `Level` parameter to `2` and the `pPrinter` parameter would point to a [`PRINTER_INFO_2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. The `PRINTER_INFO_2::pPrinterName` field lets you change the printer name.

Note that the docs for `SetPrinter` say:

> To modify the current printer settings, call the **GetPrinter** function
>   to retrieve the current settings into a **PRINTER_INFO_2** structure,
>   modify the members of that structure as necessary, and then call
>   **SetPrinter**.

So you would need to call `GetPrinter` with a properly initialized structure first, before modifying the name and calling `SetPrinter`.